# I can not close the Cursor created in a dao initializer

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am not an expert in android databases, but i can get by.  I am running up against a knowledge barrier though in figuring out how to fix this issue in our app.  We are getting errors involving cursors and i tracked it down to this function, which is a constructor in a database access object.

```
  public OrderDAO(int id) {
    // DCWEB-1520: CursorWindowAllocationException due to unclosed cursors... One source below...
    this(DB.getInstance().QueryCursor("SELECT * FROM " + TAG_VIEW_NAME + " WHERE ID=?", id, true));

}

public OrderDAO(Cursor cursor) {
    super(cursor);
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        // ACRALYZER: Prevent DAOHelper.getIn
```

I tried creating a cursor in front of it, and got a "**this** must be the first line in the constructor" error.

I also tried changing this to OrderDAO in the code and received a "method call expected" error.  I feel like i am missing something simple.

What i need to do is somehow pull that querycursor (a custom function that returns a cursor) into its own variable so i can close it after the dao is populated in the  overloaded constructor below it.  The constructor that takes an id is called from approximately 100 different places.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you for your time.